# Oracle/PLSQL Processing all data in a for LOOP after BULK COLLECT

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a problem with processing data within the for loop after bulk collect.

```
OPEN my_cursor;
LOOP
FETCH my_cursor BULK COLLECT INTO var_t LIMIT 100000;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('There is ' || var_t.COUNT || ' records found.');
EXIT WHEN my_cursor%NOTFOUND; 
FOR i IN var_t.FIRST .. var_t.LAST
LOOP
var_read_cnt := var_read_cnt + 1;
END LOOP;
END LOOP;
close my_cursor;
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('read/inserted : '|| var_read_cnt);
```

The output looks like this

There is 100000 records found.
There is 2397 records found.
manipulated : 100000

The fetch and bulk part are correct i have indeed 100000+2397 records.
But i am not able to process 2397 records in the loop because i am not getting in the loop for them.
What is the issue here ?

Comment: Well yes it should take 100 000 first, process it and the the remaining 2397

Comment: So it breaks if 100 000 records are not read ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `exit` condition is incorrect.

```
EXIT WHEN my_cursor%NOTFOUND;
```

If the `fetch` statement fetches fewer rows than is allowed by the `limit`, `%notfound` will be `true`.  But you still want to process the rows that you fetched.  The simplest approach is to change your code to

```
EXIT WHEN var_t.count = 0;
```

or to move your `exit` condition to the end of the loop rather than the beginning.